# Symfony 2 form manipulate db query

Tags: symfony, doctrine, symfony-forms, symfony-2.3

I'm having some troubles with implementing a relational database schema with symfony 2.3.2 and doctrine.

Thats's my structure:

- Details table has an one to many relation to seasons table
- Details table has an one to many relation to episodes table
- Episodes table has a many to one relation to seasons table

When symfony renders now my episode form, it's including the choice field for my seasons table, but doesn't take care about the details to seasons relationship that defines what seasons are matching that detail.

See http://fpaste.org/34835/ four sources

What would be the cleanest way now to fix that?

Comment: Please provide more details. Are your relationships bidirectional or unidirectional? What does your FormType-class look like. What does "doesn't take care..." mean? Is it not rendered or not filled out?

Comment: @mahok I just added the relevant parts in source. see http://fpaste.org/34835/

Comment: Just from quickly glancing at the source, it seems like line 61 should  have: `entity` instead of `null`: `$builder->add('season', 'entity, array('class' => 'YourMoveEpisodeClass', 'required' => false));` This should load all existing episodes from your database and display them in a choice field

Comment: that's not what I want todo. I want to show only the seasons that match with the details table from the episode...

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding what it is you are doing and what exactly is not working. Quite frankly I don't even get what your models are there for. Why do you need a Season-Model, what kind of information do you have in there that wouldn't fit more appropriately either into an episode or the general information? Please try to *explain* what you are doing and what your problem is, instead of just throwing snippets my way.